# Fitnesse/dbFit : columns that are not verified

Tags: testing, automation, fitnesse, dbfit

Do you have any ideas if it is possible to create a column that contains only description of a row and is not verified by dbFit. For instance, I have a such table:

```
 !|Query|select 1 as sth from dual|
 |sth|description|
 |1|this rows contains 1|
```

The query returns one column and only first column should be verified. The other one is skipped during verification.

Do you know if it is possible ? right now I receive the error :
     java.lang.Exception: Unknown column description
     at dbfit.fixture.RowSetFixture.findColumn(RowSetFixture.java:40)

Thank you for any help,
foxrafi

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do this with a `Query` table.

As generally this is useful for inserting data, it's possible to have a "generator" procedure which allows comments:

```
!|Execute procedure       |generate_order_line|
|col1|col2|description                        |
|1   |2   |my special case                    |
```

Then the `generate_order_line` will do the insert for you, and simply ignore the `description` parameter. This is a useful technique because you can use this for consistent data generation (eg generating consistent ids across many tables, etc).